# django registration redux ignoring changes in templates

Tags: python, django, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, django-registration

I've been struggling with Django registration redux over the past two weeks. I'm using the templates that were provided in the documentation and I've made a couple of changes like adding crispy forms and changing the button and some other stuff but the problem is that none of these changes are being shown on http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/register or any other link.
I'm using Django registration redux 1.4, Django 1.8, python 2.7.10

Comment: Where do you store your customized templates?

Comment: @arie templates/register

Answer (score 0):

Putting your customized templates in `templates/registration` (not register) should work.

At least if your `TEMPLATES` setting is correctly configured: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/upgrading/

And you probably already checked this hint from the project's [FAQ](https://django-registration-redux.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html?highlight=templates#troubleshooting)?

> I want to use custom templates, but django keeps using the admin
>   templates instead of mine!
>
> To fix this, make sure that in the INSTALLED_APPS of your settings.py
>   the entry for the registration app is placed above
>   django.contrib.admin.

Comment: Yes, I already did that. (sorry I meant templates/registration.)

Comment: And your TEMPLATES setting (see above) is correctly set for Django 1.8.? Does overwriting other templates (e.g. Django's admin templates) work?

Comment: Yes. the settings are correct, and everything else works just fine expect this part

Comment: That's strange. I just used the same app in a project and had no problems at all customizing the templates.